# Assigning a variable to pasted name of column in R

Tags: r

I have a few data frames with the names:

Meanplots1,
Meanplots2,
Meanplots3 etc.

I am trying to write a for loop to do a series of equations on each data frame.

I am attempting to use the paste0 function.

What I want to happen is for x to be a column of each data set. So the code should work like this line:

```
x <- Meanplots1$PAR
```

However, since I want to put this in a for loop I want to format it like this:

```
for (i in 1:3){
   x <- paste0("Meanplots",i,"$PAR")
   Dmodel <- nls(y ~ ((a*x)/(b + x )) - c, data = dat, start = list(a=a,b=b,c=c))
}
```

What this does is it assigns x to the list "Meanplots1$PAR" not the actual column. Any idea on how to fix this?

Comment: Please consider to provide a reproducible example.  In the code, there is `data = dat` and in the description, it says `MeanPlots1`, `MeanPlots2` etc.  while `x` is created from a different object `Meanplots1` (note that `R` is case-sensitive)

Comment: What is `dat` in the loop?  Is it the same as `MeanPlots1`, `MeanPlots2` etc

Answer (score 2, accepted):

We can get all the `data.frame` in a `list` with `mget`

```
lst1 <- mget(ls(pattern = '^MeanPlots\\d+$'))
```

then loop over the `list` with `lapply` and apply the model

```
DmodelLst <- lapply(lst1, function(dat) nls(y ~ ((a* PAR)/(b + PAR )) - c,
         data = dat, start = list(a=a,b=b,c=c)))
```

Replace 'x' with the column name 'PAR'.

---

In the OP's loop, create a NULL `list` to store the output ('Outlst'),  `get` the value of the object from `paste0`, then apply the formula with the unquoted column name i.e. 'PAR'

```
Outlst <- vector("list", 3)
ndat <- data.frame(x = seq(0,2000,100))

for(i in 1:3) {
   dat <- get(paste0("MeanPlots", i))
   modeltmp <- nls(y ~ ((a*PAR)/(b + PAR )) - c, 
          data = dat, start = list(a=a,b=b,c=c))
   MD <- data.frame(predict(modeltmp, newdata = ndat))
   MD[,2] <- ndat$x
   names(MD) <- c("Photo","PARi")
   Outlst[[i]] <- MD



  }
```

Now, we extract the output of each `list` element

```
Outlst[[1]]
Outlst[[2]]
```

instead of creating multiple objects in the global environment

Comment: In short, how do I paste a list and get r to read it as a type, not a list?

so I want the result: `x <- data$column` but I want to do this multiple times by using i.

So something like 'x <- paste0("data", i , "$column")`

Comment: @Bridger  What you are doing with ` x <- paste0("Meanplots",i,"$PAR")` may not be required if you can make it clear whether `dat` is `MeanPlots1`, `MeanPlots2` etc. in the loop

Comment: Here is the full loop
`for (i in 1:3) {
  x <- paste0("MeanPlots",i,"$RoundedPAR")
  y <- paste0("MeanPlots",i,"$Photo")
  dat <- paste0(paste0(MeanPlots,i))
  ndat <- data.frame(x = seq(0,2000,100))
  Dmodel <- nls(y ~ ((a*x)/(b + x )) - c, data = dat, start = list(a=a,b=b,c=c))
  pred <- predict(Dmodel, newdata = ndat)
  MD <- data.frame(pred)
  MD[,2] <- ndat$x
  names(MD) <- c("Photo","PARi")
  paste0("MD",i) <- MD
}`